# Playing audio in Background(Iphone os 4.0)

Tags: cocoa-touch

How to play audio in background in iphone os 4.0?

Answer (score 0):

Just set the UIBackgroundModes to audio in the info.plist.

open the info.plist as plain text file and add

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
        <string>audio</string>
</array>
```

to your plist file and save it.

All the Best.